# CURL cookie file works but not cookie themselves

Tags: curl

I can call my web service using curl like this successfully

```
curl -vL -c ~/.internal/cookie -b ~/.internal/cookie https://mywebservcie
```

this works I can see json content

Now if I open the ~/.internal/cookie file I can see 4 lines. I know that this file is in the netscape cookie file format and therefore column 6 and 7 are cookie name and content.

If now I try to call the same web service using the cookies explicitly

```
curl -vL -c"a=1" -c"b=2" -c"c=3" -c"d=4" https://mywebservice
```

I get a 401 unauthorized error.

Why does it work when I specify the whole file, but doesn't work when I specify the content of the file as individual cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -c, --cookie-jar 
>                 (HTTP)  Specify to which file you want curl to write all cookies
>                 after a completed operation. Curl writes all  cookies  from  its
>                 in-memory  cookie storage to the given file at the end of opera-
>                 tions. If no cookies are known, no data  will  be  written.  The
>                 file  will  be written using the Netscape cookie file format. If
>                 you set the file name to a single dash, "-", the cookies will be
>                 written to stdout.

-c expects a file to write cookies.

> -b, --cookie 
>                 (HTTP) Pass the data to the HTTP server in the Cookie header. It
>                 is supposedly the data previously received from the server in  a
>                 "Set-Cookie:"   line.    The   data  should  be  in  the  format
>                 "NAME1=VALUE1; NAME2=VALUE2".

Try this:

```
curl -vL -b "a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4" https://mywebservice
```